# How to set the initial index (position) for the CdkVirtualScrollViewport in Angular 7

Tags: angular, lifecycle, angular7, angular-cdk, virtualscroll

I need the inital position of the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` to be other than the first element / item of the list.

Now I found the `scrollToIndex` and `scrollTo` methods, but I only can get them to work when using it in the `ngAfterViewChecked`, which feels off.

1. Can someone confirm that the using those methods in the `ngAfterViewChecked` is the right way of doing things?
2. If not, show an alternative method / technique?

```js
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) cdkVirtualScrollViewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;
  numbers: number[] = [];

  constructor() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 10000; index++) {
      this.numbers.push(index);
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.cdkVirtualScrollViewport.scrollToIndex(2000);
  }
```

```html
  <ul class="list">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport style="height:264px" itemSize="88">
      <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let n of numbers">
        <li style="height:88px">{{ n }}</li>
      </ng-container>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? If so, please provide the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I have a not so elegant solution

```
contentCheck = 0

ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if (this.contentCheck < 3) {
  this. cdkVirtualScrollViewport.scrollToIndex(4000);
  this.contentCheck++;
 }
}
```

After 3 checks the scrollToIndex works.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a perfect solution, you can achieve this behavior by combining afterViewInit with setTimeout:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.cdkVirtualScrollViewport.scrollToIndex(50);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `setRenderedRange` method:

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) virtualScroll: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    const offset = 10; // that's an example
    if (this.virtualScroll) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const currentRange = this.virtualScroll.getRenderedRange();
            this.virtualScroll.setRenderedRange({ start: currentRange.start + offset, end: currentRange.end + offset });
        });
    }
}
```

Note: I am not sure if it is specific to my use case, but by just setting the expected range, the previous items do not seem to be considered (we cannot scroll up). It seems important to use `scrollToIndex` so the scroll is properly updated.
Here is my workaround, setting the range minus one, then scrolling by one more:

```
    const currentRange = this.virtualScroll.getRenderedRange();
    this.virtualScroll.setRenderedRange({ start: currentRange.start + offset - 1, end: currentRange.end + offset - 1});
    this. virtualScroll.scrollToIndex(offset);
```